# Tic tac toe game - my first code using pointers in cpp

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

Below is the game code written in cpp.
This is the first time I have consciously used pointers.
I can't handle the logic of winning. I have no idea how to solve this in a different, more accessible way.
I know that such straining of if statements is bad and the code is unmaintable.
I realize that for some reasons you can't use cls. What's the alternative?

```
#include <iostream>


char square[10] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9' };

int Checkwin();
void Board();
int Choice(char mark, char* square, int choice);
void showLeftNumbers(char sqiare[]);


int main()
{
    int player = 1, i, choice;


    char mark;
    do
    {
        int correctChoice = 1;
        Board();
        player = (player % 2) ? 1 : 2;

        mark = (player == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';
        int triesCount = 0;
        do
        {
            std::cout << "Player " << player << ", enter a number:  ";
            std::cin >> choice;
            correctChoice = Choice(mark, &square[choice], choice);
            triesCount++;
            if (triesCount > 2) showLeftNumbers(square);
        } while (correctChoice == 1);


        i = Checkwin();

        player++;
    } while (i == -1);
    Board();
    if (i == 1)

        std::cout << "==>\aPlayer " << --player << " win ";
    else
        std::cout << "==>\aGame draw";

    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

/*********************************************
    FUNCTION TO JUDGE THE MOVE
    IF MOVE IS RIGHT THEN IT RETURNS 0 AND
    CHANGES THE VALUE
    IF MOVE IS FORBIDEN THEN IT  RETURNS 1
**********************************************/

int Choice(char mark, char* square, int choice) {
    int compare = *square - '0';
    if (choice < 1 || choice > 10)
    {
        std::cout << "Wrong choice! You have to choose number between 1 and 9. Number " << choice << " is out of scope!\n";
        return 1;
    }
    if (compare == choice) {
        *square = mark;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Already shoot in this place\n";
        return 1;
    }
}

/*********************************************
    FUNCTION TO SHOW PLAYERS LEFT NUMBERS 
    AFTER 3 FAILED ATTEMPTS
**********************************************/

void showLeftNumbers(char sqiare[])
{
    std::cout << "Man, you can choose just between ";
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (square[i] != 'X' && square[i] != 'O')
        {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "! ";
}

/*********************************************
    FUNCTION TO RETURN GAME STATUS
    1 FOR GAME IS OVER WITH RESULT
    -1 FOR GAME IS IN PROGRESS
    O GAME IS OVER AND NO RESULT
**********************************************/

int Checkwin()
{
    if (square[1] == square[2] && square[2] == square[3])

        return 1;
    else if (square[4] == square[5] && square[5] == square[6])

        return 1;
    else if (square[7] == square[8] && square[8] == square[9])

        return 1;
    else if (square[1] == square[4] && square[4] == square[7])

        return 1;
    else if (square[2] == square[5] && square[5] == square[8])

        return 1;
    else if (square[3] == square[6] && square[6] == square[9])

        return 1;
    else if (square[1] == square[5] && square[5] == square[9])

        return 1;
    else if (square[3] == square[5] && square[5] == square[7])

        return 1;
    else if (square[1] != '1' && square[2] != '2' && square[3] != '3'
        && square[4] != '4' && square[5] != '5' && square[6] != '6'
        && square[7] != '7' && square[8] != '8' && square[9] != '9')

        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}


/*******************************************************************
     FUNCTION TO DRAW BOARD OF TIC TAC TOE WITH PLAYERS MARK
********************************************************************/


void Board()
{
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "\n\n\tTic Tac Toe\n\n";

    std::cout << "Player 1 (X)  -  Player 2 (O)\n\n\n";

    std::cout << "     |     |     \n";
    std::cout << "  " << square[1] << "  |  " << square[2] << "  |  " << square[3] << "\n";

    std::cout << "_____|_____|_____" << "\n";
    std::cout << "     |     |     " << "\n";

    std::cout << "  " << square[4] << "  |  " << square[5] << "  |  " << square[6] << "\n";

    std::cout << "_____|_____|_____" << "\n";
    std::cout << "     |     |     " << "\n";

    std::cout << "  " << square[7] << "  |  " << square[8] << "  |  " << square[9] << "\n";

    std::cout << "     |     |     \n\n";
}

/*******************************************************************
                END OF PROJECT
********************************************************************/
```

Comment: Because the code is not working as expected the question is off-topic on Code Review. We only review code that is working as expected, there are other sites that will help you debug your code. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hint the call to Checkwin() needs to be in the loop.

Comment: I was able to play a game against myself. I'm not sure where the "not working as expected" comes from.

Comment: What's the meaning of "I can't handle the logic of winning."...

Answer (score 1):

Some issues I can see:

1. I don't see many pointers. If you don't want to use them, maybe change the title of this post.
2. It's not clear what your naming convention is for functions. You have `Checkwin` and `showLeftNumbers` and `main`. I'll suggest that you should use a convention where `main` is not a rule violation, so either `snake_case` or `camelCase` (or even, God forbid, `Ada_Case_Oh_No_Make_It_Stop_Please`).
3. Don't use the same naming style for variables and functions.
4. You *can* use `cls`, but only where `cls` works -- which would be on Windows. For Unix, the corresponding program is `clear`. You can use the pre-processor `#ifdef` to check whether you are compiling a Windows or Unix program.

### `main`

1. Please don't bulk-declare unrelated variables, especially with initializers mixed in.
2. Don't mix "high level" code and "low level" code. Your `main` makes good use of calling high-level functions, but then grabs `std::cout` to do post-game wrap up. Write another function for that.
3. It looks like you just discovered the `do{}while` loop and you're over-using it a bit. Don't be afraid to (a) not use it at all; or (b) mix the while-do and do-while forms.
4. Your inner loop (with `triesCount`) should probably be a separate function (`getMove` or something).
5. Why are you referring to "Player 1" and "Player 2"? The sides are "X" and "O" and everyone knows them that way.

### `Choice`

1. DON'T USE ALL UPPER CASE FOR FUNCTION HEADER COMMENTS. IT'S HARDER TO READ THAN JUST NORMAL TEXT, AND YOUR GIANT LINE OF ASTERISKS HAS ALREADY WARNED ME THAT THE HEADER IS NOT REGULAR CODE.
2. You are validating your input (`choice`) in this function, but you should have done that in the function where you collected the input (`main`, in this case, but that should also change).
3. You return 0 or 1, but I think you mean to return `true` or `false`.

### `showLeftNumbers`

1. (minor) This may be an ESL problem, but this should probably be named `showRemainingNumbers` or `showNumbersLeft`.
2. You never print a newline.

### `Checkwin`

1. You mean `CheckWin` or `checkWin`.
2. You return either 0, 1, or -1, but only test for -1 in `main`. You are using this function in a way that it was not intended to be used.
3. Your comment about `if`s makes sense mainly in this function. IMO, this is a valid way to check for a win, but there's another opportunity for pointers here: write a function that takes a pointer to an array of three integers, and then call it eight times.
4. For extra credit, you might consider a tri-valued function that returns win, no-win, and not-yet-but-could-still-happen. Then if you ever get no-win you can stop the game immediately instead of requiring it to play out.

### `Board`

1. Move your `system("cls")` call into a separate function. Put the `"cls"` into a preprocessor macro or constant.
2. Write functions for printing a row, and printing other lines, and use them. (Hint: here's a chance to pass pointers again!)